# How can I get my entire iTunes Match-based music library to appear on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, itunes-match, music.app

I have about 12,500 tracks uploaded to iTunes Match. From my desktop and laptop, everything works great. I can see the cloud-based tracks and play them. I can download them to my machines.

When I turn on iTunes Match and select "Show All Music" on my iPhone the Music app shows me nothing at all. Specifically, it shows me this:

[image: An empty Music app]

I've tried leaving it plugged in, with the Music app open, over night to see if the progress bar fills in a bit and it never does. Not even a little bit.

If I turn off the "Show All Music" option, the Music app shows the tracks I had sync'ed to the device *before* I signed up for iTunes Match and put all my tracks in the cloud.

**How can I get my entire iTunes Match-based music library to appear on my iPhone?**

Comment: Have you previously used iTunes Match with this account on any iOS devices?

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly on my iPad and my wife's iPhone 5. My wife's iPhone 5 never had any music sync'ed to it before being connected to our match account. The iPad, like my iPhone, did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There could be a corruption in your music library that is preventing the 'sync' to finish.

1. On your iPhone, turn iTunes Match off, then open **Settings** > **General** > **Usage** > (wait for usage to populate) > **Music** > 
   tap **Edit** and then the red remove icon.
2. Restart your phone
3. When your phone is back on, open **Music** to ensure its empty. If its not, complete the above again.
4. Turn iTunes Match back on and leave the Music app open. It should take no longer than 15 minutes for it to display something other than the cloud logo.

If the issue is still persists, try deleting your Music library using [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

> ***Note: Before using [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), ensure you [have a backup of your information](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766)***

1. Download, open [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), and plug in your iPhone
2. Select **Media** on the left, and then right click **iTunes_Control** and delete that folder 
   [image: iExplorer screenshot]
3. Restart your iPhone and turn iTunes Match back on and leave the Music app open. It should take no longer than 15 minutes for it to display something other than the cloud logo.

If the issue *still* persists I would recommend you do a [complete restore through iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414)

Comment: Deleting my existing music data for the Music app via System -> Usage did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Preferences -> General
make sure iCloud library is checked!
I tried other solutions for two days, finally resorted to itunes help, and found that very important first step. Nobody else had that as I saw.

Comment: Unfortunately I had this checked and still wasn't seeing newly-added content on my mobile device. But that's awesome it worked for you!